# Postgres create view with no schema binding

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Is there a way in PostgreSQL (version 10.4) to create a view without creating table dependencies? I.e. in Redshift, there is an option to create a view [without schema binding](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_VIEW.html) but from what I can tell there is no native PostgreSQL equivalent.

Are my only options to use `DROP TABLE <table> CASCADE`, `TRUNCATE TABLE`, or use `pg_dump` to script out the dependencies, drop/recreate the table and then recreate the views, or is there another way that I can get around this?

Comment: There is no way to have a view that does not depend on its base tables. If you need to modify the table, you may have to drop the views first.

Comment: What @LaurenzAlbe said, but with the added info: in Postgres, DDL is transactional. That means you can drop the view, do other work, and re-create the view in a transaction, without danger of errors in other jobs.